# Removing lines on a chart, having dots instead with matplolib

Tags: python, plot, charts

I have a quick simple question regarding python.
My program is generating a graph by

```
plot(x,y, marker='o')
```

However, I'd like to turn off the lines and having dots instead. 
I tried

```
plot(x,y, b.) 
plot(x,y, bo)
```

which both gave me a syntax error.

I have also attached what my friend said on this: Using the `marker='bo'` keyword is adding markers, but not turning off the lines. To turn off the lines, pass in `'bo'` or `'b.'` as the third argument to plot, and skip the `marker` keyword entirely. You may want to then use the `ms` keyword to get the `marker` size right.

Hope anyone of you can help me on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `linestyle=''`?

Comment: @achampion so linestlye = none?

Comment: Looks like you left out the quotes: It's `plot(x, y, 'b.')`, not `plot(x, y, b.)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [`scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) instead?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.random_integers(0,10,10)

plt.scatter(x,y,s=200)
plt.show()
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was like Why haven't I come up with it